# How can i display a webpage in a BlackBerry Browser field?

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, browserfield

i'm developing a aplication for blackberry and i want to display a simple webpage (for example www.google.com). i'm having troubles using the examples on the blackberry developer page, can anyone give me an example that work? i'm using Eclipse and net.rim.device.api.browser.field.* api. my blackberry's device OS is 4.6

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
BrowserSession visit = Browser.getDefaultSession();
visit.displayPage("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: thank you, rupesh, but i want to embed a browser in my app, and this code call the blackberry browser.